# what changes in the weather prior to thuderstorms?

Tags: meteorology

What changes in the weather prior to thunderstorms (day before, for example)? It seems humidity goes up and temperature but is there anything else?

Comment: Temperature and humidity are the main reliable factors. If the storms come from a synoptic-scale system, the air pressure may drop.